# Tractrix & limits

Tags: calculus, limits, conic-sections, plane-curves, envelope

I'm in calculus 1 and I'm having quite a bit of trouble with this problem. Any advice as to how to obtain a solution or anything would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: Graph Example of Tractrix]

To determine the points on the curve, we need to calculate the intersection point of adjacent threads (the red lines), then determine the limit of that intersection point as the end points of the threads approach zero.

Tractrix 1

This is the situation shown in the example above: a given thread runs from the point with coördinates $(r,0)$ to the point with coördinates $(0,1-r)$, $0 ≤ r ≤ 1$.  In other words, the sum of the $x$ coördinate on the $x$-axis at the lower end of the thread and the $y$-coördinate on the $y$-axis at the upper end of the thread is one.

To determine a point on the tangent curve, consider two adjacent threads: one runs from $(r,0)$ to $(0,1-r)$; the other runs from $(r+h,0)$ to $(0,1-(r+h))$.  These lines intersect at a point $(x_{r+h},y_{r+h})$. The point on the curve is $(x_r,y_r)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}  (x_{r+h},y_{r+h})$.

1. Write the equation for the line through the points $(r,0)$ and $(0,1-r)$.
2. Write the equation for the line through the points $(r+h,0)$ and $(0,1-(r+h))$.
3. Calculate the point $(x_{r+h},y_{r+h})$ where these two lines intersect.
4. Calculate $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}  (x_{r+h},y_{r+h})$.
5. Use the point just determined to write the equation for the curve that passes through all such points.  (Note: the equation should be symmetric in $x$ and $y$.)

Comment: I took the liberty of adding your image and tweaking the TeX. Could you perhaps say where you're stuck on this question? Have you tried any of the steps in the outline? Where were you unable to proceed?

Comment: I can calculate the equations of each individual line using point-slope form, and create a general equation. I guess I'm just lost on how to go about this. Apparently, I don't quite understand.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but it's not a *tractrix*, which has one end intersecting an axis the other end asymptotically approaches the other axis. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix.

Answer (score 2):

The line joining $(r,0)$ to $(0,1-r)$ is given by
$$ \frac{x}{r}+\frac{y}{1-r} = 1 $$
(This is easy to check: just stick the two points in. To get this, take the general equation of a line $ax+by=1$, put both points in and solve simultaneously.) It's easier to work with if we write it as
$$ (1-r)x+ry-r+r^2 = 0. $$
Now, suppose we have the lines
$$ (1-r)x+ry-r+r^2 = 0 \\
 (1-r-h)x+(r+h)y-(r+h)+(r+h)^2 = 0. $$
Subtracting,
$$ -hx + hy - h + 2hr + h^2 = 0, $$
and dividing by $h$ and taking the limit as $h \to 0$ gives
$$ -x+y -1+2r = 0, $$
so we can solve for the parameter $r$:
$$ r = \frac{1}{2}(1+x-y) \implies 1-r = \frac{1}{2}(1-x+y), $$
We can use this to substitute for $r$ in the equation of the line, which gives
$$ 2(1-x+y)x+2(1+x-y)y = (1-x+y)(1+x-y) $$
after clearing denominators. Expanding gives
$$ 2x-2x^2 +4xy +2y-2y^2 = 1-x^2-y^2+2xy \\
0 = x^2 - 2xy + y^2 - 2x-2y+1 $$
This *is* symmetric in $x$ and $y$, but can be simplified further: completing the square on $x$ gives
$$ (x-y-1)^2-4y = 0, $$
so $x=1-2\sqrt{y}+y$ after choosing the appropriate root. But the right-hand side is just $(1-\sqrt{y})^2$, so, again choosing the appropriate root, this gives
$$ \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = 1 $$
as the equation.

We can verify that this is the right answer by drawing a picture:

[image: Ladder]

The solution curve is faintly visible in blue, and various straight lines joining $(0,r)$ to $(1-r,0)$ are shown in orange. Note that the blue curve is not a circle; it's actually a segment of a parabola; changing coordinates to $u=x - y-1$, $w=y$ gives the classic equation of a parabola, $u^2=4w$.

Comment: That's a nice solution to the PO's question. However, I have two comments: (1) it isn't a tractrix (not your fault; you answered the question), and (2) it is not an ellipse, but rather a superellipse of the squircle-type or an astroid, depending on how want to fill the quadrants.

Comment: I suppose actually $0 = x^2 - 2xy + y^2 - 2x-2y+1$ is the equation of a parabola, so technically it's the segment of this parabola between $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: I don't see how you got that equation. I assume you tried $(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^4 = 1$, but I don't get that result, Rather, think of it as $x^{1/2}+y^{1/2} = 1$ and you'll see that it's a superellipse.

Comment: It's a few lines up from $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=1$ in my answer. It pops straight out when substituting for $r$.

Comment: We do have the factorisation $$ x^2-2xy+y^2-2x-2y+1 = \left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}-1\right) \left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}-1\right) \left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}+1\right) \left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+1\right)), $$ though. The whole parabola is made out of the places where the first three of these vanish (the last one never vanishes, of course), and the relevant part turns out to be where the first bracket vanishes.

Comment: Can someone explain what is meant by the "appropriate roots"? I don't understand how the final answer was obtained from the second to last step

Comment: @Chappers I really appreciate you taking the time to work through this problem, however, would you be willing to explain the last couple steps how you arrived at the final equation?

Comment: @user443101 It's clear from the initial diagram that $0<x,y<1$. The other root of the quadratic $(x-y-1)^2=4y$ is $x=1+2\sqrt{y}+y = (1+\sqrt{y})^2$, which is certainly not less than $1$ for $y>0$, so we have to choose $x=1-2\sqrt{y}+y=(1-\sqrt{y})^2$, to have $x<1$. The other comes from needing to take the positive root of $(1-\sqrt{y})^2$ since $x>0$.

Comment: @Chappers Ahh I see; Thank you!